# Custom Google sign in Button asset

Tags: ios, google-signin

I want to implement a custom Google Sign-in button. I downloaded the assets from https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines and imported them:
[image]

For some reason when I use it in code:

```
Image("btn_google_light_pressed_ios")
```

the result I get is:

[image]

This looks really bad. I could obviously manually edit the asset and remove the background / change its background color to white, but I assume this is not what should be done

> Do not use the Google icon or logo by itself without the button
> boundary

Why does it look different than the actual asset ?

Update: this how other assets look like:

btn_google_light_focus_ios:

[image]

btn_google_light_normal_ios:

[image]

Looks better, but it is still not what I would like to have. This is my expected result, just with a different text:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the image which is supposed to be used for a button when pressed. Instead, you should use
`btn_google_light_focus_ios@[x]x.png` as it has white background by default.

Comment: it has indeed white background, but it also has these boundaries which make it still look not as I would expect; I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution (though not ideal) is to use images from the `web` folder ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines), [direct link](https://developers.google.com/identity/images/signin-assets.zip)):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(@2x images should be fine here as they're usually used for small sign-in buttons and not for fullscreen views)

Then, you can use the images above and add an overlay aligned to the right with a custom text and a matching background color.

Comment: It looks fine if I crop the web asset to just the icon but I can achieve the same with cropping btn_google_light_normal_ios. It is hard to believe they provide so many assets but still none of these can be used directly. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @someUs3rAndUs3r Maybe you can use the images above and add an overlay aligned to the right with a custom text and a matching background color.

Comment: an overlay sounds like the best possible solution right now ! thanks